# Format not working on right click in Files

Tags: 19.10, format

[When I right click and hit Format, absolutely nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EqTE.png)

This is on a new Ubuntu 19.10 install. I'm new to Linux but I think it should just work like in Windows?

Edit: I tried a different USB and I can format that one. The USB that is not working has some Windows files and MP4s on it, could that be the problem?

Edit: I went in to disks and deleted the partition on it, then created a new one. That seemed to work. I would still appreciate an answer just to increase my knowledge about what was going on. I'd like to learn!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the X11 version of Nautilus, which [has already been fixed upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1265), in GNOME 43, which is included in Ubuntu 22.10. The easiest solution is to update your Ubuntu. If you'd prefer to stay on 22.04, like me, the only solution is to switch to Wayland.